# configmaps are not passing properly to the containers

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, configmap

I have a kubectl config map like below.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  server.properties: |+
    server.hostname=test.com

kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config
```

And I tried to read this config inside a container.

```
containers:
        - name: testserver
          env:
            - name: server.hostname
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: my-config
                  key: server.properties.server.hostname
```

However, these configs are not passing to the container properly. Do I need do any changes to my configs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have in there isn't the right key. ConfigMaps are strictly 1 level of k/v pairs. The `|+` syntax is YAML for a multiline string but the fact the data inside that is also YAML is not something the system knows. As far as Kubernetes is concerned you have one key there, `server.properties`, with a string value that is opaque.